# Problem in Kusto Query Language with length of text

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-java-sdk

I'm working in Kusto Query Language and I would like to display not everything from the selected string.

My string is 'Execution fail against sql server. Please contact SQL Server team if you need further support. Sql error number: 50000. Error Message: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or
SUBSTRING function.'

But I would like to just display from 'Error Message: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or
SUBSTRING function.'

Could anybody help me with this problem? I don't know which function I need to use in KQL.
Thanks!

An answer on my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator). for example:

```
print input = 'Execution fail against sql server. Please contact SQL Server team if you need further support. Sql error number: 50000. Error Message: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.'
| parse input with * "Error Message:" error_message
| extend error_message = strcat("Error Message:", error_message)
```

| input | error_message |
| --- | --- |
| Execution fail against sql server. Please contact SQL Server team if you need further support. Sql error number: 50000. Error Message: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. | Error Message: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. |

Answer (score 0):

```
print MyString = 'Execution fail against sql server. Please contact SQL Server team if you need further support. Sql error number: 50000. Error Message: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.'
| parse MyString with * "Error Message:" ErrorMessage
| project ErrorMessage
```

| ErrorMessage |
| --- |
| Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WPQUsDQQyF7/6KRy8FD4sXLwUvwiqFVqpTf0DcZrdTZmemmUy14I83W0U0p+SF970ki4+K9dmpNQPuMG8/uKvqU0RPPoAG8rEoyjGgsJxYGmwCU2F0KSp1Cve8grusoEwjfI9zqojMO/RVdG+LUnNOog2ccVgkCWId31gWuL2xatBexDWXQgMvsIwnCn6HwHHQPTIJjaxGylSKgTXBwFi1D1uYz73eu+3L8unREmM3nd/Mrz4nmx36+967N9Q1Zv+zZt/ZP+PkknRge+yv/AUVScQfKQEAAA==)

If needed, concatenate *"Error Message:"* to the start of the message

```
project strcat("Error Message:", ErrorMessage)
```